# Tomcat8 error in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: server, java

I am not able to view tomcat in browser after installing it in ubuntu 16.04 server. I am pasting log below help me to solve this.

```
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Failure during filter init: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/dspace" "read"):java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/dspace" "read")
Dec 12, 2017 12:00:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
Dec 12, 2017 12:00:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/oai] startup failed due to previous errors
Dec 12, 2017 12:00:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]
Dec 12, 2017 12:00:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 23546 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

You set somewhere in config path like `/dspace` and user which run tomcat do not have permission to read this directory (if exist at all)

> Failure during filter init: **access denied** ("java.io.FilePermission"
>   "/dspace" "read"):java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
>   ("java.io.FilePermission" "/dspace" "read")