# Tomcat8: Where to find the appropriate container log file?

Tags: 16.04, webapps, tomcat

I am trying to install a webapp under Tomcat8 and get the error message in the file `catalina.2020-30-09.log`:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
```

Where can I find the "appropriate container log file"? There is no such thing in `/var/log/tomcat8` and I have no idea where this file could reside. I know the name of the failing webapp.

P.S. [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/985502/tomcat8-error-in-ubuntu-16-04) is about the same error message, but in that particular case the relevant error message was in the `catalina.out` file.

In my case, there is no error message nor other log line between the message

```
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying configuration descriptor
```

and the error message quoted above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formulating the question here helped me a lot: The "appropriate container log file" is `localhost.2020-09-30.log`.